# Upload random image from local file to html5 canvas with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, html, canvas

I have a canvas where people can doodle. I have made a button that submits each drawing to a file in my directory called "images" which is found in the main file "Espace Utopique". Each file has a different name "monimage_"time(). All this works perfectly, the images are sent to my folder in png format and I can read them.

What I am having trouble doing is inserting one of these random images into my canvas when the window opens. The idea is that people build off of other people's drawings. I have found a PHP code that I have saved in a PHP file called "retrieve.php":

```
<?php
$imagesDir = 'Espace Utopique/images';

$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{png}', GLOB_BRACE);

$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images)];
if($res) {
      echo "ok";
  }
      else {echo "ko";}
?>
```

I found codes that would let me put images into a html5 canvas:eg.

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var canvas=document.getElementById("drawing"); // grabs the canvas element
var context=canvas.getContext("2d"); // returns the 2d context object
var img=new Image() //creates a variable for a new image

img.src= "images/vft.jpg" // specifies the location of the image
context.drawImage(img,20,20); // draws the image at the specified x and y location
}
</script>
```

What I am having trouble with is putting the two together. I have tried putting this AJAX code in somewhere, but nothing seems to be working:

```
    $.ajax({


  type: "POST",
  url: "retrieve.php",


}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( msg );


});

}
```

Somebody please help me out please :) I must be missing something really obvious and silly.
Thanks!

Comment: You should echo the URL of the image in retrieve.php (not OK or whatever) and use that result in your `$.ajax.done` function (also, what is `$res`?)

Comment: $res is result, it's what I have been using to let me know if it's working or not. "If the result is achieved, echo ok, if not, echo KO". It's just for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, the two functions combined ;)

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "retrieve.php",
        succes: function( data ) {
            var canvas=document.getElementById("drawing"); // grabs the canvas element
            var context=canvas.getContext("2d"); // returns the 2d context object
            var img = new Image(); //creates a variable for a new image

            img.src = data; // specifies the location of the image
            context.drawImage(img,20,20); // draws the image at the specified x and y location
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

retrieve.php:

```
$imagesDir = 'Espace Utopique/images';

$images = glob($imagesDir . '*.{png}', GLOB_BRACE);

$randomImage = $images[array_rand($images, 1)];
if($randomImage) {
    echo $randomImage;
}
else {echo "path/to/default/image";} //in case $randomimage fails
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, for some reason it's not working. I don't get any images to the canvas.

Comment: What is stored in `$randomImage`, and what is stored in `data`. ie. what do you see when you visit `retrieve.php` directly?

Comment: I don't see why even the edited script isn't working. If I just insert an image manually it works. As soon as I throw in the php and the AJAX I get nothing.

Comment: what do you see if you visit `retrieve.php` directly?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if it did it correctly. I went to local host and opened the php file. All I get is a blank page. What should I be getting normally? By the way, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Try it with `if($randomImage != '')`

Comment: it is now showing me the path to the default image. So randomimage seems to be failing?

Comment: Yep, just place `echo $randomImage;` before the if ;) to see what `$randomImage` is.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($images)`

Comment: i get Array(0){} and I have no idea what this means... by the way, I can't thank you enough for all your help :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25794/discussion-between-amazingdreams-and-lucian-girl)